# Sharing Variables Between Multiple Instances of Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple instances of Excel calculating different parts of a problem and I want to be able to track total progress as the number of iterations completed across each instance. How can I share variables between instances of Excel?

My current thought is storing these numbers in the name manager of a master workbook and having the master workbook sum up the value for each name as a total number of iterations completed number. I've also tried the same concept by referencing the hidden namespace in the master instance of Excel as described by Chip Pearson here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/hidden.htm. Ultimately I'm struggling to keep the progress numbers across instances in memory. I do not want to write to a file that the master Excel instance references as that would slow things down quite a bit.

Inside of a working instance of Excel would be something like the following code to transmit back it's current progress to the namespace of the master workbook:

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Set xlApp = GetObject(MasterPath).Application
'The MasterPath is defined as the full path of the master instance: ActiveWorkbook.FullName
With xlApp
    .Workbooks(MasterName).Activate
    .ActiveWorkbook.Names("Thread_" & i & "_iter").RefersTo = "=" & CStr(i - seqFrom + 1)
End With
```

The above code is what is giving me errors. It gets stuck in an infinite loop. When I remove it, everything executes as expected.

In the master workbook would be something like the following to show the total progress across all instances:

```
For thread = 1 To cThreads
    progress_Arr(thread) = CLng(Right(ThisWorkbook.Names("Thread_" & thread & "_iter").RefersTo, Len(ThisWorkbook.Names("Thread_" & thread & "_iter").RefersTo) - 1))
    progress = progress + progress_Arr(thread)
    Debug.Print "Thread " & thread & ": " & progress_Arr(thread)
Next thread
```

I would ultimately like to be able to compile all of the iterations in the master instance of Excel.

Comment: The mechanics of a progress bar (as found in various tutorials) should be the same no matter the source of the data that the bar is displaying. Why not just accumulate the sum of the iteration counts in that last loop and update the bar afterwards? Also -- what do vegan wolves eat?

Comment: It's not the progress bar I'm having issues with. It's collecting the progress across all instances of Excel. I will clarify this in the post. Vegan wolves eat tofu.

Comment: It's difficult to imaging that writing to a files (or one file per instance) would really slow things down, unless you're planning on very frequent updates.

Comment: It would be between 1,000-5,000 iterations with each iteration writing to a file and saving so that the master could read it. I suppose one way to reduce that number would be to say something like only write every 5 iterations but even still that seems like a lot of writing to files, no?

Comment: Writing to a file is pretty fast...    However, if you're creating your additional instances using CreateObject, you can use public methods on the workbook object to pass messages, as long as you put a reference to the master workbook in each "slave" workbook.

Comment: I’ll give that a shot then and time it to check if performance takes any significant hit. Will report back on this. Thanks. Could you elaborate on how you might use messages here?

Answer (score 1):

Ok expanding on my comment here's my rough and ready test code: spin up a few "slave" Excel instances, load in a copy of the "driver" workbook (as readonly), and then give each slave workbook a reference to the master workbook, which they can use to call a public `LogProgress` method on the `ThisWorkbook` object.

In a regular module:

```
Option Explicit

Dim col As Collection '<< In the master, stores references to slave application instances
                      '    Not really used here though

'For "slave" workbooks - dummy "do some work" long-running 
'   routine which periodically reports back
Public Sub DoWork()
    Dim n As Long
    'kick something off...
    For n = 1 To 20
        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
        ThisWorkbook.ReportWork n '<< update master
    Next n
End Sub

'Creates slave instances loaded with copies of this workbook
'  and a reference to the master workbook, and loads them into "col"
Sub InitSlaves()
    Dim x As Long, app
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    Debug.Print "Master instance", Application.Hwnd
    Set col = New Collection
    For x = 1 To 5
        col.Add XlInstance(ThisWorkbook.FullName)
    Next x
End Sub

'Set up and return a new Excel instance
Function XlInstance(wb As String)
    Dim app, wkb
    Set app = CreateObject("excel.application")
    app.Visible = True
    Debug.Print "Slave instance", app.Hwnd
    Set wkb = app.Workbooks.Open(wb, ReadOnly:=True)
    Set wkb.Master = ThisWorkbook
    wkb.StartWork
    Set XlInstance = app
End Function
```

In the `ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Option Explicit

Dim masterWb As Object '<< in a slave workbook, a reference to the master wb

'In a slave workbook, gets a reference to the master workbook
'  Note: you *must* use 'As Object' here or you can't call the custom
'        methods later (because a "WorkBook"-type doesn't have them)
Public Property Set Master(wb As Object)
    Set masterWb = wb
End Property

'Gets called on the slave workbooks from the master
Public Sub StartWork()
   Application.OnTime Now, "DoWork"
End Sub

'From a slave, send a message back to the master workbook
Public Sub ReportWork(msg)
    masterWb.LogProgress Application.Hwnd, msg
End Sub

'In the master, get a message from a slave workbook
Public Sub LogProgress(id, msg)
    Dim m
    m = Application.Match(id, Sheet1.Columns(1), 0)
    If IsError(m) Then
        m = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Sheet1.Cells(m, 1).Value = id
    End If
    Sheet1.Cells(m, 2).Value = msg
End Sub
```